# How do I create a JS Discord bot that relays whatever text is PMed to it into a channel of a discord server?

Tags: javascript, copy, bots, paste, discord

As the title would suggest, I would like to create a Discord Bot which performs the following function.

A user PMs the bot and the bot would copy the text and paste it into a text channel of a Discord server together with the user's discord name. That's really all I need it to do but I don't know how to program a Discord Bot.

It would be best if someone teaches me but if you give me all the code I'd simply just try to read it and teach myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know javascript though? If not I recommend you learn some, specifically nodejs - at least the basic syntax. After that, you can take a look at the docs for using the api wrapper, `discord.js` here https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome to build your bot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install node.js and npm.

Open the command prompt and use 'CD /yourbotfolder'

Install discord.js using npm. (npm install --save discord.js)

Create a new Javascript file.

Paste this into it:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
var server;
var DChannel;

bot.on('ready', () => {
    server = bot.guilds.get(YOUR_SERVER_ID);
    DChannel = server.channels.get(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID);
    console.log('--------------------\n\n\nREADY: '+ new Date() +'\n\n\n--------------------');
});

bot.on('message', (message)=>{
    if (message.channel.type.toLowerCase() == 'dm' || message.channel.type.toLowerCase() == 'group') {
        var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(message.content)
        .setTimestamp(new Date())
        .setColor('#C735D4');
        DChannel.send(embed);
    }
});
bot.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

> How to get a channel's id:
>   Right click on the channel, then click on 'Copy ID'
>
> How to get your server's id:
>   Right click on your server's icon in your server list, then click on 'Copy ID'

Now open the command prompt
Type 'CD /yourbotfolder' again and then run this:
`node yourbotfile.js`